# Month-until-date rolling calculation in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, rolling-sum

Can anyone help with calculating sales figures for month-until-date rolling sum on a data table carrying Datetime column and Sales figures column?

Using OVER in standard sql can help me calculate rows/dates preceding the current row, but I am having trouble with starting from day one of a month.

Comment: It's always good to add an example for both: input and expected result table. Could you add these?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I cannot put the exact tables here. But imagine just a simple two-column table--one with sales transaction timestamps and other with sales figures. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create columns for day, month, year (see:[date extract function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#extract)), you can use the month and year in the "PARTITION BY" part of your OVER function and the day in the "ORDER BY" part.

**UPDATE**

[AliveToLearn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6366499/alivetolearn) worked it out: AVG(events_US) OVER (Partition by event_month, event_year ORDER BY day) AS moving_avg_month

Comment: Bobby thanks a lot! My primary rolling query for 28 days cumulative has this: AVG(events_US) OVER (ORDER BY day RANGE BETWEEN 27 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS mov_avg_28d     //// Would you please elaborate the changed OVER clause? Thanks a lot

Comment: Alright, I worked it out: 
AVG(events_US) OVER (Partition by event_month, event_year ORDER BY day) AS moving_avg_month //thanks a lot for your help!!